# RecyclerView large space is creating between each items

Tags: android

Though i have set the RecyclerView height to wrap_content,space is being created between items.At the start of the app there are about some elements(that can be fit on the screen) without space but when i scroll again large space is being created between each items

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

ViewHolder Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="GradleDependency">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desgn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/designation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desgn"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The `RecyclerView` height has nothing to do with the space between items. Please post your viewholder xlm layout

Comment: I have edited the question as you asked

Comment: Got it..Thank you..Your Question gave me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

check your custom layout. In that you have to change `match_parent` into `wrap_content`.

If this layout inflating in your layout change this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  //todo made the changes here
tools:ignore="GradleDependency">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desgn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/designation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/Name"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desgn"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
```